# How to visualize free heap chunks using Python GDB command

Tags: python, binary, gdb, heap-memory, exploit

I need to visualize free heap chunks like the following:

```
free fast bin chunks:
chunk 1:
address=...
prev_size=...
size=...
fd=...
bk=...
fd_nextsize=...
bk_nextsize=...
data=...

chunk 2:
....
....

free large bin chunks:
chunk 1:
....

free unsorted bin chunks:
....
```

So far I have managed to do it using `heap` command in pwndbg and some string parsing inside a python script that I pass to gdb using `--command=my_command.py` flag.

The problem is I have to use vanilla gdb, and I wasn't able to find a similar command or method to visualise free heap chunks.

What I was doing previously was using:

```
x = gdb.parse_and_eval('main_arena.bins')
bins_string = x.format_string(max_elements=254)
bins = bins_string[1:-1].split(',')
```

and then iterating over all free chunks in `bins` and calling `heap {chunk_address}` for each of them and parsing the output.

How can I do this without using `heap` with the means of vanilla gdb?

UPDATE: I would also like to skip tcache chunks but I am not sure how to tell if it is tcache or other type without the `heap` command

I will appreciate your help!